# Cursor not working for fetching video from device

Tags: java, android, cursor

I am trying to implement on click media(Video/Images) function in my chat app when user click on any media it opens new fragment with app folder of images or video like whatsapp and telegram.

I implemented code which open app folder for images and shows all images. Here i need to show all images like i am doing but show first image which user clicked on. for this i have image full name like this `/storage/emulated/0/xmpp/Media/xmpp Images/xmpp IMG_1582477568462.jpg` .

For video i am also using same code but i am getting 0 result from cursor. I don't know what what's wrong with my code

```
private ArrayList<String> getFolderItems(String folderName, String fileName, int type){
        String[] colums = null ;
        String orderBy = null;
        String columsName = null;
        Uri uri = null;
        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String folder = /storage/emulated/0/xmpp/Media/xmpp Images+folderName;
        Log.d(TAG, "getFolderItems: "+folderName+" "+fileName+" "+type);
        Log.d(TAG, "getFolderItems: Destination Folder == "+folder);
        // 0 for images 1 for video
        if (type == 0){
            Log.d(TAG,"Type == 0");
            colums = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
            orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
            uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            columsName =  MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA;
            selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + folder + "%"};
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG,"Type == 1");
            colums = new String[]{MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media._ID};
            orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC";
            uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            columsName =  MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
            selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " like ? ";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + folder + "%"};
        }


        Cursor cursor = MyApplication.getmContext().getContentResolver().query(
                uri,
                colums,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                orderBy);

        int count = cursor.getCount();
        if (galleryItems == null){
            galleryItems = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <count ; i++) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(i);
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(columsName);
            Log.d(TAG, "getFolderItems: "+cursor.getString(index));
            galleryItems.add(cursor.getString(index));
        }
        cursor.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "getFolderItems: Gallery Item Size == "+galleryItems.size());
        return galleryItems;
    }
```

for showing images/video i am using `RecyclerView`
and i am also cross checked if video exist in folder with correct name
`Video_1583239285257.mp4`

So above code has 2 issue which i need to resolve. Please help me in this.

**1: Not getting any result for video cursor**

**2: Unable to move to particular image user click when showing to user**